# Display data from grouped Pandas DataFrame in Jinja

Tags: python, group-by, jinja2

I'm completely lost. I need to reformat data structure I'm fetching from DB. The query is simple. As I need to

```
def get_all_data_from_db( database_file ):
    connection = sqlite3.connect( database_file )
    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT id, sourceIP, destIP FROM assigned_ips', connection )
    group_df = df.groupby('DestIP')
    connection.close()
    return( group_df )
```

Resulting dataframe is used in flask as data source to fill out template. What I need to achieve is something like:

```
  {% for destIP, assignments in data %}
    <h2>{{ destIP }}</h2>
      {% for singleSourceIP in assignments.items() %}
          <p>{{ singleSourceIP[0] }}</p>  <!-- What should I put here?? -->
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The code above does work. It returns data of pandas.core.series.Series type.

Now this is where the problem is. I cannot get to the data inside the series (I don't know how to do it). I just want to display all source IPs as paragraphs for each unique Destination IP as H1.
Maybe my approach is not correct since the beggining. Maybe it's a dead end. I need advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found is to cast result to string. This method allows for different combinations with dataframe, eg. to disable headers, indexes and more. Resulting string can be easily formated by spliting.

```
{% for destIP, assignments in data %}
<h2>{{ destIP }}</h2>
  {% for i in SourceIP.to_string( columns=["SourceIP"], header=False, index=False ).split( "\n" ) %}
      <p>{{ i }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```